# Regex find first and second ," occurence in every line

Tags: php, regex, text

I have a lot of lines formatted as this:

```
{"id":1,"Melbourne is the capital of Australia.","correct":0,"Canberra is the capital of Australia."},
```

I need it to be converted to this new format:

```
{"id":1,"statement":"Melbourne is the capital of Australia.","correct":0,"answer":"Canberra is the capital of Australia."},
```

I could do that if I could find the first and second occurence of `,"` in each line

Comment: Where are these lines coming from? They look like a failed attempt at generating JSON. It might be easier to fix the source of this data so it outputs valid JSON instead of munging strings on your end…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how strict is pattern you want in practice, but this one should work

Regex: `'(\{".*?":\d+\,)(.*)(".*?"\})'`

Substitution: `'\1"statement":\2"answer":\3'`

**Explanation**

`(\{".*?":\d+\,)` capture text from the starting of `{` to the first occurrence of `,`,

`(.*)` capture text between the the above pattern and the below pattern.

`(".*?"\})` capture text from the last occurrence of `,` to the ending of `}`,

where the capturings go to the variable `\1`, `\2`, `\3` respectively.

**Additional**

From your new request that you want regex to be also work with

`{"id":3,"Paris is the capital of France.","correct":1,NULL}`

The solution is you just replace the last regex

`(".*?"\})`

to

`((?:".*?"|NULL)\})`

**Explanation**

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group which means you want to group some pattern together but without capturing them to variable such as `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, `...`,

`|` is an alternation.

see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cB5wH8/3)

Answer (score 0):

The approach without preg_replace:

```
$str = '{"id":1,"Melbourne is the capital of Australia.","correct":0,"Canberra is the capital of Australia."}';

$str = explode(',',$str);
$str[1] = '"statement":'.$str[1];
$str[3] = '"answer":'.$str[3];
$str = implode(',',$str);

var_dump(json_decode($str, true));
```